# How to use Fuzzy GUI editor in Scilab?

Tags: scilab, fuzzy-logic

I've installed [Fuzzy Logic Toolbox](http://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/sciFLT) on Scilab 5.4.1

In Matlab we can write `fuzzy` in command line and use fuzzy GUI editor.

How to use Fuzzy GUI editor in Scilab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the particular toolbox but using `help sciFLT` I found `editfls`, maybe this can help you on your way.